# Discord.py: How to implement ytsearch on the play command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, youtube-dl

Hi guys I created this music bot and I want to implement the ytsearch on the play button like the bot "Rythm". For the moment it can play music only with an url but I want my bot to be able to play from url and from keywords (like !play never gonna give you up) with the same command, but I have no idea how to do this. Can you guys help me?

```
musics= {}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL()

class Video:
    def __init__(self, link):
        video = ytdl.extract_info(link, download = False)
        video_format = video["formats"][0]
        self.url =video["webpage_url"]
        self.stream_url =video_format["url"]

def play_song(client, queue, song):
    source= discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song.stream_url
    , before_options = "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5"))
    
    def next(_):
        if len(queue)>0:
            new_song= queue[0]
            del queue[0]
            play_song(client, queue, new_song)
        else:
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(client.disconnect(), bot.loop)
    
    
    client.play(source, after=next)


@bot.command()
async def play (ctx, url):
    client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if client and client.channel:
        video = Video(url)
        musics[ctx.guild].append(video)
    else:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        video = Video(url)
        musics[ctx.guild] = []
        client = await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"Playing : {video.url}")
        play_song(client, musics[ctx.guild], video)
```

Edit:
So after triying to add the ytdl_options it gives me this error, even without the --noplaylist, it still gives me the same error (the music that I'm triying to play is blinding lights).

```
ytdl_options = {
    'noplaylist': True,
    'default_search': 'auto'
}


ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_options)
```

```
[download] Downloading playlist: blinding
[youtube:search] query "blinding": Downloading page 1
[youtube:search] playlist blinding: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] 4NRXx6U8ABQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video 4NRXx6U8ABQ because of --no-playlist
[download] Finished downloading playlist: blinding
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pietr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\pietr\Desktop\Discord bot\Discord bot", line 152, in play
    video = Video(url)
  File "c:\Users\pietr\Desktop\Discord bot\Discord bot", line 93, in __init__
    video_format = video["formats"][0]
KeyError: 'formats'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pietr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\pietr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pietr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'formats'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `YoutubeDL` object, you can specify its default search behaviour by setting the `default_search` option.

Quoted from [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#options) (emphasis mine):

> Use this prefix for unqualified URLs. For example "gvsearch2:" downloads two videos from google videos for youtube-dl "large apple". **Use the value "auto" to let youtube-dl guess** ("auto_warning" to emit a warning when guessing). "error" just throws an error. The default value "fixup_error" repairs broken URLs, but emits an error if this is not possible instead of searching.

```py
ytdl_options = {'default_search': 'auto'}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_options)
```

You need to handle cases where a search is done, as the returned format is different to when a valid URL is supplied.

```py
import youtube_dl

ytdl_options = {
    'noplaylist': True,
    'default_search': 'auto'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_options)

link = 'test search'

video = ytdl.extract_info(link, download = False)

if 'entries' in video:
    video_format = video['entries'][0]["formats"][0]
elif 'formats' in video:
    video_format = video["formats"][0]

url = video["webpage_url"]
stream_url = video_format["url"]
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me a key error: 'formats'. What should i do??

Comment: Can you show me what you are trying as well as the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I edited my post with the error that I'm having, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably would like to look at the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets). Change the `resource` to `search` and then click on `list (by keyword)`. You'll get sample code on it.

You will first need to [Obtain authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) in order to get it to work properly.